How to determine year of the downloaded soil organic carbon
I am looking a help to determine year of downloaded soil organic carbon stock data from SoilGrids.
How can I know the year in which the data was uploaded here in SoilGrids?

The data you downloaded don't really have a "year" as they're not measurements at a specific point in time, they're predictions (though they are interpolated from samples).
However, the FAQ does note that the date each grid was produced is in the metadata:

Each GeoTiff available from the SoilGrids.org website carries the
production date in the metadata, enabling different versions of the
maps to be traced and compared.
For more info see:
https://files.isric.org/soilgrids/latest/data

You may also be interested in the reference at the top of the FAQ which goes into more detail, including the date ranges for some of the samples:

Poggio, L., de Sousa, L. M., Batjes, N. H., Heuvelink, G. B. M.,
Kempen, B., Ribeiro, E., and Rossiter, D.: SoilGrids 2.0: producing
soil information for the globe with quantified spatial uncertainty,
SOIL, 7, 217–240, 2021. DOI

